# numpy, how to get elements of an array that form part of a record in another array

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = np.array([1,7])
c = 2
```

How could I get elements of B where there exists a record in A where the first column is an element of B and the second column equals c?

Comment: second part is simple `A[ A[:,1] == c ]`

Answer (score 0):

I found method only with `for`-loop

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = np.array([1,7])
c = 2

for x in B:
    result = A[ (A[:,0] == x) & (A[:,1] == c) ]
    if len(result) > 0:  # `if result:` doesn't work because it is `numpy.array`
        print(x, '=>', result)
```

Result:

```
1 => [[1 2 3]]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Without `for`-loop

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,3,9]])
B = np.array([1,7])
c = 2

result = B[ A[ (A[:,1] == c), 0 ] == B ]

print(result)
```